# How do we draw a line representing the natural numbers and rays from one vertice to another?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to know how we can draw an horizontal line with the natural numbers highlighted as well as rays starting from one vertice in the direction towards the right hand side direction.

This is what I can get as far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) node[above] {0} -- +(1,0) node[above] {1};

\draw (1,0) -- +(1,0) node[above] {2};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I can get the lines between two consecutive vertices, but I am unable to draw a black ball at each vertice as well as drawing rays from the vertice 1 to 2, for example.

Comment: Showing an attempt in work or a diagram of the desired result would be more helpful.

Comment: @Leucippus Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I received answer solve your problem, please consider to accept them (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer.  If not, please write a comment, where clarify what you miss in it or what is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are asking for something like this.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) foreach \x in {1,...,6}   
 { -- ++ (1,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,label=below:$\x$](\x){}};
 \draw foreach \i in {1,...,5}
  {(1) to[out=\i*15,in=180-\i*15] (2)
  (1) to[out=-\i*15,in=180+\i*15] (2)};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]